# Trying to update database but the form only inserts blank entries

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a site where the user registers and logs in and then is taken to a page to enter data.

I have successfully been able to recall all the fields in the database as input values into my form and I want to be able to update these values with a save button before submitting.

I have two form buttons providing different actions based on javascript.

I don't receive any errors but when I hit the save button no entries submit to my database.

I am pulling the unique key (email address) from the database and am trying to update all of the fields associated with the row the unique email address is in. I have this field as a hidden input that gets added to the submission when the save button is clicked.

Ive tried REPLACE, ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to update the entry but it still does nothing. Here is my code:

```
<div style="float:left;  width:450px;">
<form id="parts" class="form" name="parts" method="post" ><br>
<input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="<? echo $_SESSION['MM_Username']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="<? echo $user['first_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="<? echo $user['last_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="business_name" name="business_name" value="<? echo $user['business_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="occupation" name="occupation" value="<? echo $user['occupation']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="business_address_1" name="business_address_1" value="<? echo $user['business_address_1']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="business_address_2" name="business_address_2" value="<? echo $user['business_address_2']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="country" name="country" value="<? echo $user['country']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="city" name="city" value="<? echo $user['city']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="state_province" name="state_province" value="<? echo $user['state_province']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="zip" name="zip" value="<? echo $user['zip']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="phone" name="phone" value="<? echo $user['phone']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="special_offers" name="special_offers" value="<? echo $user['special_offers']; ?>">

  <div id="div1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="div2">SET PART #</div>
  <div id="div3">INSTALL DATE</div>

  <div id="div1">1.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_1" name="part_1" value="<? echo $user['part_1']; ?>">     </div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_1_install_date" name="part_1_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_1_install_date']; ?>"> </div>

  <div id="div1">2.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_2" name="part_2" value="<? echo $user['part_2']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_2_install_date" name="part_2_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_2_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">3.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_3" name="part_3" value="<? echo $user['part_3']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_3_install_date" name="part_3_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_3_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">4.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_4" name="part_4" value="<? echo $user['part_4']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_4_install_date" name="part_4_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_4_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">5.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_5" name="part_5" value="<? echo $user['part_5']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_5_install_date" name="part_5_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_5_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">6.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_6" name="part_6" value="<? echo $user['part_6']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_6_install_date" name="part_6_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_6_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">7.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_7" name="part_7" value="<? echo $user['part_7']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_7_install_date" name="part_7_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_7_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">8.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_8" name="part_8" value="<? echo $user['part_8']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_8_install_date" name="part_8_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_8_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">9.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_9" name="part_9" value="<? echo $user['part_9']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_9_install_date" name="part_9_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_9_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">10.</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="text" id="part_10" name="part_10" value="<? echo $user['part_10']; ?>"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input type="text" id="part_10_install_date" name="part_10_install_date" value="<? echo $user['part_10_install_date']; ?>"></div>

  <div id="div1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="div2"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick="submitForm('save.php')"></div>
  <div id="div3"><input class="send" id="register" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm('submit.php')" disabled="disabled"></div>
</form>

<a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>

</div>
```

Here is my save button onclick action:

```
<?php
include("includes/connection.php");


$sql = "INSERT INTO login (email, first_name, last_name, business_name, occupation, business_address_1, business_address_2, country, city, state_province, zip, phone, special_offers, part_1, part_1_install_date, part_2, part_2_install_date, part_3, part_3_install_date, part_4, part_4_install_date, part_5, part_5_install_date, part_6, part_6_install_date, part_7, part_7_install_date, part_8, part_8_install_date, part_9, part_9_install_date, part_10, part_10_install_date)
VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$_POST[first_name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[business_name]','$_POST[occupation]','$_POST[business_address_1]','$_POST[business_address_2]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[city]','$_POST[state_province]','$_POST[zip]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[special_offers]','$_POST[part_1]', '$_POST[part_1_install_date]', '$_POST[part_2]', '$_POST[part_2_install_date]', '$_POST[part_3]', '$_POST[part_3_install_date]', '$_POST[part_4]', '$_POST[part_4_install_date]', '$_POST[part_5]', '$_POST[part_5_install_date]', '$_POST[part_6]', '$_POST[part_6_install_date]', '$_POST[part_7]', '$_POST[part_7_install_date]', '$_POST[part_8]', '$_POST[part_8_install_date]', '$_POST[part_9]', '$_POST[part_9_install_date]', '$_POST[part_10]', '$_POST[part_10_install_date]')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE login SET column = 'email' WHERE column='$_POST[email]'";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
echo header('Location: login-ENG.php');
} else {
 echo mysqli_error($connection);
}




mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Here is the javascript to differentiate button functions:

```
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('parts').action = action;
    document.getElementById('parts').submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, did you start the session?

Comment: What does the javascript look like? And you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: Had you used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), would have thrown you "Undefined index...." to infinity... and beyond. Plus, make sure short tags are enabled.

Comment: The page has a session started, I have the page set where you cannot access it unless you log in first otherwise it kicks you back to the login page. I tried to add error reporting but it does not display anything seeing as that on success it navigates you to another page. I believe it thinks that the submission was successful therefore it does not display any errors. @Fred -ii-

Comment: @Fred -ii- I updated my code based on Marc's answer but now nothing is submitting to the database at all

Comment: Try the query without the JS. If it works, you'll know what to go after.

Comment: However this is incorrect `UPDATE email='$_POST[email]'` (I think, I could be wrong) - UPDATE syntax is `UPDATE table SET column='value' WHERE column='x'` - Try removing it also.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I tried to change the UPDATE syntax to: 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE login SET column = 'email' WHERE column='$_POST[email]' and I am getting a syntax error. I updated my code above. When I removed it it warned me about creating a duplicate entry.

Comment: `UPDATE login SET column = 'email' WHERE column='$_POST[email]'` that was just an example I gave you earlier. You need to use your actual column name(s) you wish to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NONE of your form fields have `name` attributes. Without `name=...`, there's nothing to submit. `id` attributes are not relevant at all for form submission. A simple `var_dump($_POST)` would have shown you this.

```
<input type="text" name="email" ... />
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        |
     VALUES ('$_POST[email]','$
```

As well, you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: And not to forget that array indexing inside of strings only works when you enclose the vars with {}

Comment: @ITroubs: irrelevant. OP isn't. `"$arr[foo]"` - perfectly fine. `"$arr['foo']"` - wrong. `"{$arr['foo']}"` - fine.

Comment: Not only is it vulnerable to SQL injection, it's also vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: Told the OP to use error reporting 5 minutes prior; nada. That would've thrown Undefined indexes. Meh, what can you do.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that, duh. After adding name attributes to all of the fields the database is no longer adding a blank entry but it is now doing nothing at all. I don't see any errors either. I updated my code above. @Marc B

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST)`. confirm that your form is actually working.